# mysql table Paasword column adding amp; in the end

Tags: php, mysql

I created a mysql table and the data is inserted in the table by input tag using php. When I insert a password value in table's password column by using `<input type="password">`. It automatically  adds `amp;` in the end of the string. How to remove it?

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
echo $username;
echo $password;
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "register");
if (!$connection) {
    die("can not connect to database");
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM signupinfo WHERE username= '" . $username . "' AND password ='" . $password . "' ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if (!$result) {
    die(mysqli_error($connection));
}
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    echo "login successfull";
} else {
    echo "sorry incorrect password or username";
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing passwords as plaintext?

Answer (score -1):

There could 3 possibilities:

1) Check the character set of your password field, it should be utf8_general_ci

OR

2) Remove unwanted spaces like:

SELECT * FROM signupinfo WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'

OR

3) Decode your password variable like:

SELECT * FROM signupinfo WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".html_entity_decode($password)."'

Answer (score -1):

Can you please share your PHP code for submitting it on DB.
I think you are sending it via GET method.
And it is similar like -

submitdemo.php?username=test **&** password=test **&**

Or may be something like this in POST method.
Please check that you are not sending extra **&** on the last of the parameter string.